# 3D sphere oblique impacts calculations

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, vectors, computational-physics, simulations

Im creating a physics simulator and im struggling to expand my collisions from 2D to 3D. In 2D the velocity only changes parallel to the line of center so I presume this is the same for 3D.I can get a Cartesian equation of line but Im not sure how to get the velocity component relative to this line.

So my question is how can I create a relative axis which would let me use linear momentum conservation or more generically how to Calculate the final velocity of 3D sphere collisions.

Comment: What is the scope of your simulation?  Are you simulating a single collision (for which you wouldn't actually need a simulation) or are you imagining two spheres bouncing around inside some domain and colliding repeatedly?  Or do you have more than two spheres?

Comment: The Simulation is of my school's Physics course allowing for multiple sphere in an open area where multiple collisions can occur.I have this made in 1 and 2 dimensional space but unsure of the mathematics in 3D.

Comment: Are there any external forces, such as gravity?  Do the spheres have different sizes or speeds?

Comment: No external forces(closed system) , uniform spheres which different velocities.

Comment: I'm curious as to why there's a vote to migrate this question to [math.se]; how does this question (even v1) look like a math question??

Answer (score 0):

Given the constraints you mention in the comments, you would first start with the position and velocity vectors of the two spheres ($\vec r_1, \vec v_1, \vec r_2, \vec v_2$). When the positions of the spheres meet the criteria for collision (e.g. $|\vec r_1 - \vec r_2|<2R$, where $R$ is the radius of the spheres), you would do the following:

1. Define the unit vector which points from the center of the first sphere to the center of the second - $\hat \delta = \frac{\vec r_1 - \vec r_2}{|\vec r_1 - \vec r_2|}$.
2. Break the velocities up into components parallel to and perpendicular to this unit vector - e.g. $\vec v_1 = \vec v_{1,\parallel}+\vec v_{1,\perp}$ where $\vec v_{1,\parallel} = (\vec v_1 \cdot \hat \delta) \hat \delta$ and $\vec v_{1,\perp} = \vec v_1 - (\vec v_1 \cdot \hat \delta)\hat \delta$
3. Note that the perpendicular velocities will be unchanged by the collision, while the parallel velocities will not be.  In the case of a perfectly elastic collision, the parallel velocities should be exchanged.  If $\vec v$ represents the velocity before the collision and $\vec u$ represents the velocity after the collision, you should find that

$$ \vec u_1 = (\vec v_2\cdot \hat \delta)\hat \delta + [\vec v_1 - (\vec v_1\cdot \hat \delta)\hat \delta] = \vec v_1 - [(\vec v_1 - \vec v_2)\cdot \hat \delta]\hat \delta$$
and
$$ \vec u_2 = \vec v_2 + [(\vec v_1 - \vec v_2)\cdot \hat \delta]\hat \delta$$

You can check to see that these equations satisfy the conservation of momentum and the conservation of energy, and that they reproduce your results in 2D and 1D.  Obviously if the masses are different then things will get a bit more complicated, but the point is that most of the work is done on pencil and paper.

In pseudocode, given a list of $n$ positions and velocities, you'd do the following at each time step:

```
for i = 1 to n-1:
    for j = i+1 to n:
        if dist(r[i] - r[j]) < 2R:
            delta = (r[i] - r[j])/dist(r[i]-r[j])
            transfer = dot(v[i]-v[j],delta)*delta
            v[i] -= transfer
            v[j] += transfer
```

where you'd need to figure out how to define and manipulate vectors as appropriate.  This obviously also only works as long as you don't have collisions between three or more particles, so they'd have to be sufficiently spread out in your domain, and you'd have to include some kind of check to handle things if more than two particles happen to intersect.

Comment: Thank you.I was close to getting it but didnt minus the relative velocity from total velocity.